# Perl regexp substitution of an array

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to use Perl script A to generate and replace an array in Perl script B.

Script B originally contains something like:

```
my @old_array = (value1, value2, etc);
```

Script A contains something like:

```
for ( $a = 0; $a < $nr_values; $a++ ) {

    $list .= "$new_values[$a], ";
}
```

```
`perl -pi -e 's/^my \@old_array.*/my \@new_array \= \( $list \)\;/g' script_B.pl;`
```

However, when I run Perl script A

- The substitution occurs to all of the `my` declared variables
- The array `@` symbol and name are not changed: only the updated values

Please advise how to properly substitute arrays using Perl?

Comment: What you call *Running the script* looks like a Perl one-liner; it certainly has nothing to do with `script_A.pl`. Have you perhaps just added that bash command to your Perl script? If that's what you've done then it wouldn't compile. Please show the whole of `script_A.pl` and explain where you have entered your `perl -pi -e ...` command.

Comment: Someone reformatted my question incorrectly and removed the original bash quotes. Yes, the perl one-liner is embedded in my perl script (script a), and has worked fine in the past for quick plaintext substitutions in the context of a larger script.

Comment: Why would you shell out to Perl from within a Perl script? That... seems... sub-optimal.

Comment: It is sub-optimal. Feel free to suggest both an optimal and functional alternative.

Comment: You need to read [***Markdown help***](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and learn how to use Markdown to format your posts. Don't just make wild guesses and make things up—you need to be *accurate*.

Comment: I agree that my question could have been formatted better, but I’m not sure what wild guesses I made? My original question was worded properly, and as far as I can tell, the only updates that have been made were highlighting/spacing ones. I will read the Markdown, though, for future posts.

Comment: Replace that `for` loop with `my $list = join ', ', @new_array;`.

Comment: Yes, the current iteration of the question looks correct. Thank you.

Comment: I think the code you're showing is too different from your *real* code for us to be able to help. What you've put here won't affect *"all of the my declared variables"*.

Comment: The join command appears to yield identical behavior to what I had before, i.e. does not insert the new @ symbol or name (my  = ( )). I would prefer not pasting all 531 lines of the original code, as 99% of it is unrelated math used to generate the updated numerical values. It seems like an issue when I attempt to utilize the @ symbol in regex, since this routine works fine for all other characters.

Comment: Is there something that's preventing you from refactoring or modifying the target script? Rather than trying to reach in and change the values, you'd be better off writing modular code that could accept different parameters.

Comment: You could try using templates to generate your file, then you no longer have the issue of using regular expressions, as you explicitly mark the places where substitutions should happen.  It also handles looping and hash constructs nicely:  http://www.template-toolkit.org/

Comment: @Zero: If you refuse either to show your full program or to create and publish a minimal version that displays the same issues as the original then there is nothing that we can do to help you. The `for` loop and `qx//` shell call you show are pretty much irrelevant as they don't malfunction in the way you describe. Most of us are highly-experienced professionals, but that does not mean we can debug a Perl program from only a bug-free part of that code and some vague hand-waving from you.

Comment: Is your `\`` and `;` backwards at the end of your perl shell line?

Comment: Depending on your environment, replace `perl -e` with `echo` and see what is output? Consider using `system` instead of backticks?

Comment: Matt & Felix -- thank you for your suggestions. I'll likely rewrite the code to accept command-line input array values instead of hardcoding them and writing over each iteration.

Comment: Borodin - I can confirm that this behavior persists with simplified code, and has nothing to do with the generation of the new array values.
(modify.pl)
`#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my @temps = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my $foo;
my $bar;`
(test.pl)
`#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
system("perl -pi -e 's/^my \@temps.*/my \@temps \= \( NEW \)\;/g' modify.pl");`

Replaces all of the declared variables in the first perl script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proper solution using triple backslashes:

`perl -pi -e 's/^my \\\@temps.*/my \\\@temps \= \( NEW \)\;/g' modify.pl`;

This solves both my regex find and replace issues.

For those attempting to help with substantive comments, thank you! For those insisting that I was not providing enough information, or that my issue was caused by unlisted code, I found your responses to be highly unprofessional and not focused on the question being asked.